# Remove the space between bars and axis

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using pgfplots to create a y bar chart. 
I would like to remove the space marked in red, between the bars and the axis/the right border. These are stacked bar charts which are "clustered" using a trick I found here.

I thought by setting the bar width to 6pt it would remove the spaces, but it doesn't, it just overlaps every bar.

Also, any idea, on how to make a nice looking grid to improve clarity?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}%
\definecolor{bluegray}{RGB}{1, 171, 170}%
\definecolor{neuesrot}{RGB}{207, 103, 102}%
\definecolor{ultramarin}{RGB}{40, 109, 168}%
\definecolor{hellesgrau}{RGB}{216, 216, 216}%
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=9cm, bar shift=-3pt, width=20cm, bar width=5pt, ybar stacked, ymax=47, ymin=1, xtick=data, ytick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,47}, x tick label style={font=\tiny, rotate=75, anchor=east}, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.50)},anchor=north}, legend columns=-1, symbolic x coords={BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,
},
    legend entries={Schädigungsstufe A,Schädigungsstufe B,Schädigungsstufe D,Schädigungsstufe E}
]
\addplot +[fill=bluegray, draw=black] coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,18)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,14)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,20)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,18)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,8)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,5)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,3)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,3)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,1)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,1)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,0)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,6)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,8)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,5)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,1)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,2)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,5)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,23)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,24)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,28)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,16)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,9)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,10)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,12)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,4)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,8)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,1)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,5)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,20)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,2)
};
\addplot +[fill=amber, draw=black] coordinates  {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,10)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,16)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,12)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,25)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,6)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,0)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,5)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,3)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,44)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,5)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,3)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,1)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,1)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,2)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,14)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,7)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,8)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,9)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,25)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,10)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,10)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,11)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,8)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,16)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,7)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,7)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,12)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,10)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,14)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,8)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,5)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,4)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,4)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,10)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,1)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,2)
};
\addplot +[fill=neuesrot, draw=black] coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,15)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,12)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,11)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,0)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,0)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,16)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,9)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,6)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,6)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,8)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,9)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,11)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,19)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,19)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,8)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,16)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,15)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,32)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,16)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,16)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,7)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,12)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,16)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,26)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,15)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,21)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,15)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,6)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,12)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,17)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,6)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,5)
};
\addplot+[fill=hellesgrau, draw=black] coordinates{(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,5)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,27)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,0)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,22)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,26)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,37)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,38)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,39)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,34)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,34)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,34)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,34)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,42)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,43)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,35)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,22)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,15)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,12)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,25)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,5)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,20)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,0)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,17)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,8)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,12)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,23)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,32)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,32)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,41)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,35)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,41)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,26)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,34)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,37)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,42)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,38)
};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[height=9cm, width=20cm, bar shift=2pt, bar width=5pt, ybar stacked, ymax=47, ymin=1, xtick=data, ytick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,47}, x tick label style={font=\tiny, rotate=75, anchor=east},
          symbolic x coords={BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,
BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,
BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,
BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,
BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,
BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,
BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,
DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,
DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,
DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,
DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,
}
]

\addplot  +[fill=bluegray, draw=black]coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,21)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,14)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,17)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,22)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,5)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,8)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,3)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,3)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,5)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,1)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,2)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,0)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,8)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,13)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,6)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,0)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,1)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,11)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,20)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,30)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,29)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,12)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,9)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,14)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,13)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,1)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,3)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,20)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,2)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,2)

};
\addplot  +[fill=amber, draw=black] coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,11)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,20)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,16)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,12)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,6)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,5)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,4)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,6)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,4)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,3)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,2)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,10)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,12)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,11)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,9)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,20)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,24)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,9)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,20)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,15)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,14)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,10)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,10)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,15)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,10)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,34)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,6)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,6)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,4)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,2)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,4)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,7)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,8)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,5)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,6)
};
\addplot  +[fill=neuesrot, draw=black]coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,13)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,6)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,12)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,33)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,20)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,19)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,8)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,5)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,10)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,2)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,11)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,11)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,0)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,37)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,20)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,14)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,25)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,27)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,21)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,27)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,25)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,12)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,3)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,8)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,25)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,23)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,23)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,15)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,16)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,6)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,15)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,15)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,5)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,15)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,19)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,1)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,13)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,11)
};
\addplot  +[fill=hellesgrau, draw=black] coordinates {(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,2)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,7)
(BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,1)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,34)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,0)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,12)
(BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,16)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,32)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,33)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,30)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,32)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,42)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,38)
(BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,27)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,36)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,32)
(BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,0)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,0)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,7)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,9)
(BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,7)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,0)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,1)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,0)
(BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,0)
(DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,23)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,21)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,31)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,25)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,25)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,43)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,36)
(DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,22)
(DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,0)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,41)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,27)
(DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,28)

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ergebnisse der Einschätzung der Nitalätzung}
\label{nitaldata1}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problem spaces marked in red]

Comment: Does \begin{axis}[ enlarge  x limits=false,...    help?

Comment: It helps (in addition with bar width=6pt, it even looks close the way I want it), but it removes the first and the last bar for some reason. I think it is because I have two axis to be able to cluster the stacked bar charts. It's making everything quite complicated, to be honest. Edit: It's because of the bar shift of 3pt. Is it possible to set the enlarge x limits to 3pt to each site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already written in the comments below the question, you need to reduce the value for `enlarge x limits` *exactly*, but unfortunately you cannot do it with absolute (axis) coordinates when `symbolic coordinates` are used. (That means currently one is not allowed to write something like `bar width=[normalize]0.5` or `bar shift=[normalize]0.25`.)

To circumvent this problem I don't use `symbolic coordinates` directly. I first create an inline/temporary data table from your data given to the `\addplot` commands and secondly use `xticklabels from table` to simulate the `symbolic x coords` feature. By doing this I can now normally use the absolute `bar with` and `bar shift` options.

Last I simply provide -- also in absolute (axis) coordinates -- a suitable absolute value for `enlarge x limits`.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% needed to store an inline table
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use relative (axis) coordinates
        % for `bar width' and `bar shift'
        compat=1.7,
        % created a style for the stuff that is common in both axis
        my axis style/.style={
            height=9cm,
            width=20cm,
            % give an absolute (axis) coordinate value for the `bar width'
            bar width=0.5,
            ybar stacked,
            ymax=47,
            ymin=1,
            % give an absolute (axis) coordinate value to enlarge the x limits
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        },
    }
    % store the data as inline table
    % (here I used a comma as column separator, because there are spaces in the
    %  x column)
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        x,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4
        BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-1,18,10,15,4,21,11,13,2
        BGH\_0.65\_1\_160 B-2,14,16,12,5,14,20,6,7
        BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-3,20,12,11,4,17,16,7,7
        BGH\_0.65\_1\_190 B-4,18,25,0,4,22,12,12,1
        BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-5,10,6,4,27,10,2,1,34
        BGH\_0.8\_1\_160 B-6,8,0,0,0,4,10,33,0
        BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-7,4,5,16,22,5,10,20,12
        BGH\_0.8\_1\_190 B-8,5,7,9,26,8,4,19,16
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-9,0,4,6,37,0,0,0,0
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160 B-10,2,3,4,38,3,4,8,32
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-11,3,44,0,0,3,6,5,33
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190 B-12,3,1,4,39,2,5,10,30
        BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-13,1,2,10,34,1,4,10,32
        BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_160 B-14,2,5,6,34,2,1,2,42
        BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-15,2,3,8,34,1,6,2,38
        BGH\_0.8\_2.2\_190 B-16,2,4,7,34,5,4,11,27
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V B-20,2,1,2,42,2,2,7,36
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-21,1,1,2,43,1,3,11,32
        BGH\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V B-22,1,2,9,35,2,2,0,0
        BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-01,0,14,11,22,0,10,37,0
        BGH2\_0.65\_1\_190 B2-02,6,7,19,15,8,12,20,7
        BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-03,8,8,19,12,13,11,14,9
        BGH2\_0.65\_1\_160 B2-04,5,9,8,25,6,9,25,7
        BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-05,1,25,16,5,0,20,27,0
        BGH2\_0.8\_1\_190 B2-06,2,10,15,20,1,24,21,1
        BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-07,5,10,32,0,11,9,27,0
        BGH2\_0.8\_1\_160 B2-08,3,11,16,17,2,20,25,0
        DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-02,23,8,16,0,20,15,12,0
        DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-03,24,16,7,0,30,14,3,0
        DEW\_0.65\_1\_190 D-04,28,7,12,0,29,10,8,0
        DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-05,16,7,16,8,12,10,25,0
        DEW\_0.8\_1\_160 D-06,9,12,26,0,9,15,23,0
        DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-07,10,10,15,12,14,10,23,0
        DEW\_0.8\_1\_190 D-08,12,14,21,0,13,34,0,0
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-09,4,5,15,23,3,6,15,23
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160 D-10,5,8,2,32,5,5,16,21
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-11,8,2,5,32,5,5,6,31
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190 D-12,2,2,2,41,1,6,15,25
        DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-13,1,5,6,35,3,4,15,25
        DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_160 D-14,2,4,0,41,2,2,0,43
        DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-15,5,4,12,26,2,4,5,36
        DEW\_0.8\_2.2\_190 D-16,3,5,5,34,3,7,15,22
        DEW\_0.65\_1\_160 D-17,20,10,17,0,20,8,19,0
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_160\_2.V D-19,2,2,6,37,2,3,1,41
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-21,2,1,2,42,2,5,13,27
        DEW\_0.65\_2.2\_190\_2.V D-22,2,2,5,38,2,6,11,28
    }{\loadedtable}
    \definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
    \definecolor{bluegray}{RGB}{1, 171, 170}
    \definecolor{neuesrot}{RGB}{207, 103, 102}
    \definecolor{ultramarin}{RGB}{40, 109, 168}
    \definecolor{hellesgrau}{RGB}{216, 216, 216}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % apply previously defined style here
        my axis style,
        % provide the shift of the bar, which should be half of the `bar width'
        bar shift=-0.25,
        % just use `data' for the `xtick's ...
        xtick=data,
        % ... and label them with the values from the `x' column of the loaded table
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{x},
        ytick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,47},
        x tick label style={
            font=\tiny,
            rotate=75,
            anchor=east,
        },
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.50)},
            anchor=north,
        },
        legend columns=-1,
        legend entries={
            Schädigungsstufe A,
            Schädigungsstufe B,
            Schädigungsstufe D,
            Schädigungsstufe E,
        },
    ]
        % then simply add the plots by using the `\coordindex' as x values
        % and the corresponding y columns for the "left" stacked ybars
        \addplot+ [fill=bluegray, draw=black]   table [x expr=\coordindex,y=y1] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=amber, draw=black]      table [x expr=\coordindex,y=y2] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=neuesrot, draw=black]   table [x expr=\coordindex,y=y3] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=hellesgrau, draw=black] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=y4] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        % same as before
        my axis style,
        % same as before but this time the positive value
        bar shift=0.25,
        % we don't need to draw the x and y ticks again
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
    ]
        % same as before, but this time with the columns for the "right" stacked ybars
        \addplot+ [fill=bluegray, draw=black]   table [x expr=\coordindex,y=z1] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=amber, draw=black]      table [x expr=\coordindex,y=z2] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=neuesrot, draw=black]   table [x expr=\coordindex,y=z3] {\loadedtable};
        \addplot+ [fill=hellesgrau, draw=black] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=z4] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. I had to add `enlarge x limits={abs=6pt}` to both of the axis options, to help the issue with the bar shift. Thanks to Bobyandbob for pointing me in the right direction.