# LaTeX barplot: one x-axis, two y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot a bar plot with LaTeX with the layout that you can see in the picture that I've done with PowerPoint:

[image: desired bar plot example]

I don't want to do a subplot kind of graph since the datasets include the same data but collected in two different moments of an experiment.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Hi, welcome. You could have a look at the `pgfplots` package and its `groupplots` library. (Don't have time to write up a solution now, but someone else might.)

Comment: Hello and thanks to those who have replied.. Since it seems that my request was too generic, I've posted a follow-up question here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355517/follow-up-particular-bar-plot-help-needed

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an easy task for [PGFPlots](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Because you weren't very specific for your needs, here I also just present an *example* on how to do it, using some dummy data copied from the manual.

If you have experimental data in a file and you need to use "symbolic coordinates", please also have a look at [Remove the space between bars and axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355401/remove-the-space-between-bars-and-axis). And if you really should need  a second y-axis, also this can be done. For that have a look at [Second y-axis inside groupplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251190/second-y-axis-inside-groupplot).

Hopefully this gives you at least a good start. If you later need some more assistance in details, please feel free to ask a [Follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) then.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                y descriptions at=edge left,
                vertical sep=5mm,
            },
            ybar,
            enlargelimits=0.15,
            ylabel={\#participants},
            xtick=data,
            symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
            nodes near coords,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for you example.. It is similar to what I need, but as I said, I didn't want two subplot.. I'm trying to draw a single plot with two different layers (in the same bounding box)... and with a single legend.. Any idea for that?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure if I understand what you mean. The presented solution *has* only one bounding box. I am not sure what you mean with "different layers". Could you elaborate that in more detail, please. Best by editing your question and maybe adding a sketch of the desired result. Adding a single legend is also easy. There was more than one question ask here about this topic, so I guess you will find a solution that fits your needs. I don't state an example here, because you didn't specify any "boundary conditions" on how it should look like.

Comment: Since you asked a [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355517/follow-up-particular-bar-plot) could you think of accepting this answer so it gets of the "still open" list. Many thanks.

Comment: @Davide won't have been notified of those comments I think, Stefan, as they are under your answer.