# Follow-up: Particular bar plot.

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, groupplots, axis

#### This is a follow-up question to: [LaTeX barplot: one x-axis, two y-axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355479/latex-barplot-one-x-axis-two-y-axis)

In the previous question, I got some useful advice, but I also noticed that my description of the desired bar-plot was not enough.

So now I've made a more detailed example of the bar plot I want, and I hope someone can help me to realize it.

This is it:

[image: example of desired chart]

So it is a single plot in which two different sets of the same variables are shown. One legend, one x-axis and a short description of the data set on the left..

I've tried the subplot, but it's not what I want. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan's code in your other question already did most of that, and can be easily modified. How does this look? Comments in the code indicate where things have been added or modified.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                y descriptions at=edge left,
                vertical sep=0mm, % modified
                group name=G % added
            },
            ybar,
            axis lines=left, % added
            enlargelimits=0.15,
            ylabel={\#participants},
            xtick=data,
            symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
            nodes near coords,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
            \legend{a,b,c} % added
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)};
            \addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \node [rotate=90] at (G c1r1.east) {Data set 1}; % added
    \node [rotate=90] at (G c1r2.east) {Data set 2}; % added

    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); % added 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```